# Seamless title bar and terminal background?

Tags: macos, terminal, high-sierra, iterm

How can I make the title (and tab) bar of iTerm 2 exactly the same color as the terminal background so that it's impossible to tell where one starts and the other begins?

How it is at the moment:

[image]

What I'd like it to be:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Sorry I don't really know for sure, but there is no option for that I know of. As a last resort you could edit the source code for the interface, [you could fork there](https://github.com/gnachman/iTerm2).

If you wanted you can check the advanced tab in the preferences, but i don't think you'll be successful there.